# ActiveRecord find through has_one association child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have models like this:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments 
  has_one :special_comment, :class_name => "Comment"
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
  # contains author
end
```

How can I select every `Discussion` through its adjoined `:special_comment` 'author' association. Effectively I want to do something like:

```
select * from discussions 
inner join comments on comments.discussion_id=discussion.id 
where comments.author = 'poopface'
```

I get something close with this:

> > Discussion.find(:all, :conditions => {:author => 'poopface'}, :joins => :special_comment)
> >     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: discussions.author: SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions"   INNER JOIN "comments" ON comments.discussion_id = discussions.id  WHERE ("discussions"."author" = 'poopface')

But it should be `WHERE ("comments"."author" = 'poopface')`

Thanks!

Comment: What is the has_one using to identify the 'special_comment' rather than the other comments?  has_one is used instead of belongs_to where your foreign key is on the other object. Is this your situation?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Discussion.all(:conditions => {:comments=> {:author => "blah"}}, 
          :joins => :comments)
```

OR

```
Discussion.all(:conditions => ["comments.author = ?", "blah"], 
          :joins => :comments)
```

**Note:** May be you could have used a better author name in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some foreignkey on your Comments table that your has_one is referencing...

```
Discussion.find(:all, :conditions => {:comments=>{:author => 'blah'}}, 
                    :joins => :special_comment)
```

will give you all Discussions where special_comment is authored by 'blah'.

```
Discussion.find(:all, :conditions => {:comments=>{:author => 'blah'}}, 
                    :joins => :comments)
```

will give you all Discussions where they have any comments authored by 'blah'.

Comment: This will throw a SQL error. The hash key `special_comment` is used as the table alias for `discussions` table, by the `find` call. The table alias for the `discussions` table is `discussions`. This is a known limitation while using nested hash for conditions.

Comment: fair point.. It should be 'comments' then.. special_comment is a reference to a comment not a discussion. - I believe.